# URL truncated when using regex

Tags: regex, perl, cut

I'm trying to extract an URL from an HTTP GET response, so something like "http://xxxxxxxxx.com" has to be extracted.

```
(https?):\/\/(www\.)?[a-z0-9\.:].*?(?=\s)
```

But when I get it, using let's say...

```
$var = "http://www.google.co.uk"
print $var =~ m/(https?):\/\/(www\.)?[a-z0-9\.:].*?(?=\s)/ig;
```

The string shown is truncated, like: "http://www.google.com" and nothing else.

Why is this happening?

While using `REGEXR` the text doesn't cut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the positive lookahead assertion.

```
my $var = "http://www.google.co.uk";
print $var =~ m/https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?[a-z0-9\.:]\S+/ig;
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I didn't realize about the positive lookahead.

Comment: The only thing I don't understand is why while using Regexp online it worked perfectly whilst in Perl it didn't. I guess it was luck.

Comment: it was not a luck. I think in the online regex tester, there is a newline character exists after to the `http://www.google.co.uk` line, so it finds a match. `\s` matches any horizontal or vertical space character (including line breaks)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
my $var = "http://www.google.co.uk";
if ($var =~ m!((https?)://(www\.)?[a-z0-9.:]*)!ig)
{
    print "$1\n";
}
```